# In the Python debugger pdb, how do you exit interactive mode without terminating the debugging session

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

Using python 3.5.1

When I run a script using the python debugger module:

```
  [home]# python -m pdb myscript.py
```

This starts a debug session:

```
  > /somepath/to/myscript.py(1)<module>()
  -> import os
  (Pdb)
```

If I want to enter an interactive terminal from within the debug session I can issue the `interact` command:

```
(Pdb) interact
*interactive*
>>>
```

Now I can interact with th code as if I was in a running python interactive mode, with access to any functions or variable in scope of the script running in the debugger at the time I entered `interact` mode.

When I issue the command to exit the interactive mode (to continue debugging) it kills the entire debug session:

```
>>> exit()
The program exited via sys.exit(). Exit status: None
....long nasty stack trace here....

[home]#
```

I've also tried `quit()` and it also terminates the debugger.

How can you exit out of `interact` mode without terminating the entire debug session?   Is this even possible?

Ideally, I'd like to return to into debug mode at the point where I left off so I could continue stepping through my code.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Sending an [`EOF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> should work:

```
$ python -m pdb myscript.py
> .../myscript.py(1)<module>()
-> import os
(Pdb) import code
(Pdb) code.interact()
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec 27 2015, 01:48:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> <CTRL-D>
(Pdb) c
...
```

Comment: Bonus tip: `CTRL-D` is also incredibly handy for closing dozens of open terminal / SSH sessions at the end of a long day of work: It will (usually) immediately close that tab in your terminal emulator, **except** if there's still a half-typed command on the command line or a running program in the foreground.

Comment: I think CTRL-D just killed my entire Spyder instance.

Comment: In jupyter notebook (in firefox) it does not work. Ctrl+D is for creating a bookmark. Also discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522316/exit-pdb-interactive-mode-from-jupyter-notebook?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `ipdb`, and are on `Windows/Windows10`, you should use `Cntrl-Z`>`Return` to get out of the interactive shell.

Tested in `ipython/python 3.5` and `ipdb` and `pdb`

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3603#issuecomment-747392494

`from pandas.io.clipboard import copy; copy("\x04")`

Copies Ctrl-D to your clipboard, and the you can paste it and enter.

Answer (score 4):

For those who look for a solution in jupyter notebook (and just yet do not want to learn emacs). I found one which worked for me (from [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3603#issuecomment-408488791)).

In linux shell:

```sh
echo ^D | xclip -selection clipboard
```

But, you do NOT type ^D as characters but as `ctrl-v ctrl-d`...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Emacs and accessing the `pdb` interact mode through `M-x shell`, the best I could find was to call `comint-quit-subjob` (`C-c C-\`).  This kills the entire debug session and returns you to the shell session rather than killing the entire shell process as `comint-send-eof` (`C-c C-d`) would do.

```
(venv) c:\projects\my-project> python my-entry-point.py

    550         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace(context=10)
--> 551         print("First line to start debugging at")

ipdb> interact
*interactive*
In : # call M-x comint-quit-subjob (C-c C-\)
^C
(venv) c:\projects\my-project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Spyder (on Gnome), I cannot type `Ctrl+D` or `Ctrl+Shift+U`.  So to escape interactive mode, I open a text editor, type `Ctrl+Shift+U` then, without letting go of `Ctrl+Shift`, I press `Ctrl+Shift+4`.  This places a character in the text editor that I can highlight and copy.  I then paste it into the interactive mode of Spyder and I can get out of interactive mode and back into the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, press Ctrl + Z and give Enter.

Answer (score 0):

**In Python 3**, use the Interactive Interpreter:

```
(Pdb) code.interact()
>>> (Enter your commands)
>>> ...
>>> exit() # Exit interactive mode
(Pdb) c
```

You can also import "code" in your main code and just use `code.interact()` in "Pdb" mode.

Re: https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html

(Note: `exit()` doesn't work in interactive mode in Python 2)

Comment: Mac, Python3, `exit()` will exit the whole debugging session and it's not possible to `c` after that.

Comment: Well, I don't know anymore what this `code.interact()` is and where it is used.  If I use it in PDB in my PY3, I get a nice "name 'code' is not defined"!  And it I use `exit()` the script is just terminated.

Answer (score -2):

On a related note, if you want to exit the debugger entirely you just press `q` then enter.