# Exit pdb Interactive Mode from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook

Within `pdb`, I'm using the interact command to enter interactive mode ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)).

This gives me an InteractiveConsole within `pdb` (which I need in order to do list comprehension).

From within a Jupyter Notebook, how do I leave interactive mode without exiting the debugger entirely?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945059/in-the-python-debugger-pdb-how-do-you-exit-interactive-mode-without-terminating) is the exact same question but the solutions only work from the terminal.

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> from within Jupyter just adds a bookmark.
- And `quit()` returns `NameError: name 'quit' is not defined`

I can do `import sys; sys.exit()`, but that exits the debugger entirely, meaning I have to start from scratch.

Comment: I filed a bug on the Python issue tracker asking to add a command to exit the PDB InteractiveConsole: https://bugs.python.org/issue41096

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution similar to triccare's which doesn't require Emacs.

Run this command on Linux:

```
echo '\x04' | xclip -selection clipboard
```

or this command on macOS:

```
echo '\x04' | pbcopy
```

and then paste into PDB interactive prompt in Jupyter and press enter.

How this works: This puts the ASCII character 0x04, "END OF TRANSMISSION", onto your clipboard. This character is a "control character" that signals that there is no more input, which causes the PDB interactive session to end.

Answer (score 6):

A platform-agnostic method to solve this is to use `pandas` (doesn't require the terminal or Emac) :

- Run this in the interactive console itself:

  ```
  from pandas.io.clipboard import copy; copy("\x04")
  ```
- And then do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste the 'end of transmittion charecter' and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have been success is to copy/paste the Crtl-D character from another source. I use Emacs, so this is fairly easy, but any text editor that allows you to insert a Crtl-D into the document should work. Once inserted, use the standard copy/paste into the pdb interact field and hit  or . This should get you out.

For Emacs, the long way is as follows, for demonstration purposes:

```
M-x insert char <RET> END OF TRANSMISSION <RET>
```

At this point you should see ^D in the buffer. At this point select the character and M-w or kill-ring-save to put it on the clipboard.

Then, change to the browser and make the interactive field active, and paste the character back. You will not see anything. Then hit . This should/might get you out.